# Typescript - How can I return the Type of the child

Tags: typescript

If I pass a Class I'd like to return its type. Right now I cast the type after returning the parent's type.

I'd Like to avoid the casting and preserving all intellisense features, is there a way?

Below is an example of implementations and what I'd like to achieve

```
class Component {
    get name(): string {
        return this.constructor.name
    }
}

class Direction extends Component {
    x: number
    y: number

    constructor(x: number = 0, y: number = 0) {
        super()
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Component {
    x: number
    y: number
    w: number
    h: number

    constructor(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number) {
        super()
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.w = w
        this.h = h
    }
}
```

```
class Entity {
    components: Map<string, Component>

    constructor(...components: Component[]) {
        this.components = new Map()

        components.forEach(component => this.add(component))
    }

    get(component: Function): Component | undefined {
        return this.components.get(component.name)
    }

    add(component: Component) {
        this.components.set(component.name, component)
    }
}

const player = new Entity(
                    new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100),
                    new Direction(1, 1)
                )

const shape = player.get(Rectangle) as Rectangle
const direction = player.get(Direction) as Direction
```

Example of what I'd like to have

```
get(component: Function): ?? return the child type somehow ?? | undefined {
    return this.components.get(component.name)
}

const shape = player.get(Rectangle) // No casting
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even work at runtime; https://tsplay.dev/mL20Aw

Comment: Also, what if you have multiple components of the same type? Then you could only have one instance of each... I'd worry about how your code works at runtime before getting the types right.

Comment: Edited the code, now should work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need a generic so that the type of the given constructor is retained in the return type:

```
get<C extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(component: C): InstanceType<C> | undefined {
    return this.components.get(component.name) as InstanceType<C>;
}
```

Since we're passing a *class* and not an *instance*, the type of `component` should be a constructor. Then in the return type, to get the type of an instance, we use the built-in `InstanceType`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKOZZW)

---

@kikon's shorter (and better) version:

```
get<T>(component: new (...args: any[]) => T): T | undefined {
    return this.components.get(component.name) as T;
}
```

This removes the need for `InstanceType` as it lets the compiler infer the instance type for us (as `T`) and the generic constraint.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJX0kN)

Comment: Just beautiful! I was about to say it's not possible ... Maybe it can be slightly simplified to `get<T>(component: new (...args: any[]) => T): T | undefined { return this.components.get(component.name) as T}` ?

Comment: To make it "safer" I constrained the type of the value at a generic key too. 
```get<T extends Component>(component: new (...args: any[]) => T): T | undefined { return this.components.get(component.name) as T}```